# How to restart Java method after termination

Tags: java, validation, if-statement, methods

I'm new to Java and thought I would make one of the classic Username and Password validation programs which I have successfully made with no obvious bugs, however I would like the program to essentially restart the input if the user enters the in-correct information. How would I go about restarting the program successfully each time the users enters wrong information?

Code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class UserPass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String user; //Creating user-name variable.
        String pass; //Creating password variable.


        System.out.println("Enter username here: "); //Message to tell user to input the user-name.
        user = input.nextLine(); //Taking the users user-name input.

        System.out.println("Enter the password here: "); //Message to tell user to input the password.
        pass = input.nextLine(); //Taking the users password input.

        //Validating the users User-name and password input.
        if(user.equals("Shane") && (pass.equals("Temple"))) {
            System.out.println("Correct!"); //If the User-name and password are both correct then a message will tell the user that they are correct.
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("The Usernname or Password that you have entered was in-correct"); //If above conditions are not met then message will tell the user that they have entered the wrong user-name or password
        }
    }

}
```

I know this is extremely basic as I said I'm very new to Java (2 hours ago new).

I thought of calling the "main" method inside the else condition statement however I heard It's bas practice to use the "main" method any more times than when the program first starts.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Add a loop that keeps taking input until it is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you wanted.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserPass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String user; //Creating user-name variable.
        String pass; //Creating password variable.
        boolean isValidUser = false;

        while(!isValidUser) {
            System.out.println("Enter username here: "); //Message to tell user to input the user-name.
            user = input.nextLine(); //Taking the users user-name input.

            System.out.println("Enter the password here: "); //Message to tell user to input the password.
            pass = input.nextLine(); //Taking the users password input.

            //Validating the users User-name and password input.
            if(user.equals("Shane") && (pass.equals("Temple"))) {
                System.out.println("Correct!"); 
                isValidUser = true;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("The Usernname or Password that you have entered was in-correct"); 
                isValidUser = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That works wonders thank you, always been too intimidated by loops haha. Going to need to work with them at some point, thank you :)

Comment: I do have one question; the "!" infront of "isValidUser... what does that mean? Would (isValidUser.equals (true) / (false) not work?

Comment: That means if not valid user, since "isValidUser" initialized as false which means still user is not valid. This variable is made as "true" only when user and password is matched.

Comment: Oh so thats so the program know when to loop/stop looping. Okay that makes sense :)